# Where to start to write a Python script for sync local directory to Google Drive?

Tags: python, linux, google-drive-api

I am learning Python and because of lack of google drive client for Linux. I want to write a simple script to just sync the local directory with google drive. It doesn't have to be fancy and rich feature. Just a command line and do the sync manually is OK.

Is it there's any existing projects I can start with? Or anyone can list me some topics I should start learning for it?

Answer (score 2):

You could try PyDrive, which claims to be an easier-to-use wrapper around the base Google Drive API: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDrive

If that doesn't do it for you, I suppose you should just look at the API reference here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/ and consider Python packages like "requests" or "urllib2" to do the HTTP stuff.